# replacing words after numbers in a list of strings

Tags: list, replace

I am new to Python. I know how to replace but this is exactly what I want to do and I can't write a function for it:

Input:

```
list_a=['ball', 'red', '2', 'fly', 'bee' , '3' , 'bag']
list_b=['2' , '3']
x= 'Blue'
```

#I extracted the numbers from list_a in form of list_b=['2' , '3'].
#Now I want to replace every word in list_a which is located after a number(list_b) with the string x which is 'Blue'.

so the desired output:

```
list_c=['ball' , 'red' , '2' , 'Blue' , 'bee' , '3' , 'Blue']
```

Many thanks in advance

so the desired output:

list_c=['ball' , 'red' , '2' , 'Blue' , 'bee' , '3' , 'Blue']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the solution

```
list_a=['ball', 'red', '2', 'fly', 'bee' , '3' , 'bag']
list_b=['2' , '3']
x= 'Blue'
lst=[]
for i in list_b:
    lst.append(list_a.index(i))

print(lst)

for j in lst:
    list_a[j+1] = x
print(list_a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this does not give me the desired output. I see append in your code but I needed to Replace actually

Comment: @shahinsyr append is used to capture the position of the occurrence of "2" or "3" . then further the code is to replace the very next string with "Blue" you can print list_a at last and see the result.

Comment: Now I get it, perfect thanks a lot